# Rails 4 automatic timestamp without using modified_at/created_at?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

What is the best way in rails 4 to automatically update a modified at column and created at column, given that the names of the columns can be anything? i.e. not set to the default created_at and updated_at names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `touch` method:  http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Timestamp/touch

```
model.touch(:attribute)
```

This works in previous versions of Rails.

Answer (score 0):

`touch` is a good solution, but sends an extra SQL UPDATE query immediately. You can also just manually set `custom_at = Time.now.utc`, either in a `before_save` callback, or as needed.